# Is there a way to ensure a control does not enter the boundaries of another control?

Tags: c#

I'm using windows forms c# in visual studio 2019
I have a picture box, "pb_sheep_apex", and I am moving it a random location after it has been clicked.
I have an "if" statement (code included below) to determine if the new random location is within the boundaries of another control, as I want it to remain in empty space and not cover any of the HUD.

```
if ((pb_sheep_easy.Location.X > (pb_heart.Location.X - pb_sheep_easy.Width) && 
        pb_sheep_easy.Location.Y < (pb_heart.Location.Y + pb_heart.Height)) || 
    (pb_sheep_easy.Location.X < (lbl_timeRemaining.Location.X + lbl_timeRemaining.Width) && 
        pb_sheep_easy.Location.Y < (lbl_timeRemaining.Location.Y + lbl_timeRemaining.Height)))
{
    Reposition(Width, Height, pb_sheep_easy, pb_sheep_hard, pb_sheep_apex);
}
```

This if statement occurs when the `pb_sheep_apex_LocationChanged` event is triggered and checks if the picture box is within the boundaries of another control, which if true should call the reposition method until the picture is relocated to a position outside the boundaries of the control, however the picture box can somehow be displayed within the boundaries of the control.
I cannot find a fault in the if statement but it doesn't function how I would like it to. If anyone could find the fault I would be very grateful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersect?view=net-6.0

Comment: @HansPassant

the following code using rectangles still does not work 

`Rectangle sheep = new Rectangle(pb_sheep_easy.Location, pb_sheep_easy.Size);
            Rectangle timer = new Rectangle(lbl_timeRemaining.Location, lbl_timeRemaining.Size);
            Rectangle healthBar = new Rectangle(lbl_healthBounds.Location, lbl_healthBounds.Size);

            if(sheep.IntersectsWith(timer) || sheep.IntersectsWith(healthBar))
            {
                Reposition(Width, Height, pb_sheep_easy, pb_sheep_hard, pb_sheep_apex);
            }`

Comment: @HansPassant if you want a cleaner version of the code i can post another question

Comment: No need to ask a new question - you can edit your question to add the code from your comment. Also, including examples of ways in which the code doesn't behave as you'd expect will help us to work out how to make it behave as you'd expect.